# Tirar barra de rolagem no ionic 3

Tags: css3, ionic, ionic3

Estou com dificuldade para tirar a barra de rolagem no `ionic 3` esta aparecendo em todas as versões `(ios, android, windows phone)`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente tirar com css :

```
* {
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Abraço.

Comment: Não funcionou, tentei colocar no app.scss

Comment: altera ai fiz assim e deu * {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

Comment: Viu se ele 'setou' esse atributo ? Tente colocar "!important" antes do ";" do hidden.